# How to say "I heard you like flowers" in Japanese?

Tags: translation

So google translate gives me this, but this sounds strange to me.

> 花が好きだって聞いた

Is that sentence correct? I am writing to a very close Japanese friend so we always talk in non-polite Japanese but I just don't know how to use the past form to create this sentence.

Comment: Why does it sound strange and how would you say this in your own words?

Comment: i would say あなたが花が好きだって聞いたよ。

Comment: So what is strange about the translation from Google Translate?

Comment: I would say 「花が好きなんだってね。」(casual)「花が好きだそうですね。」(polite)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. 花が好きだって聞いた。 (Google Translate)
> 2. **あなたが**花が好きだって聞いた**よ**。 (Your attempt)

Both sentences are perfectly fine, at least grammatically. I don't know why you thought the first sentence is "wrong". Still, since your attempt is close to the original one, let me clarify the difference introduced by your addition of あなたが and よ.

It's a good idea to add よ at the end. Sentence 1 is not unnatural, but if you say this before you give a bouquet to someone, it may sound a little blunt, because of the lack of "emotion" added by sentence-end よ/ね/！/etc. Sentence 1 looks like this was said by a silent and introvert character in fiction. If you felt you wanted to use よ at the end, that's very good.

On the other hand, it's a bad idea to add あなたが. It's not just unnecessary, but it's harmful. Basically you should never use such a polite second-person pronoun when you talk to your close friend. The best approach is to omit the person pronoun because it can be inferred from the context.

Basically Google Translate is very bad at dealing with register, formality, keigo and role words. They do not know who you are and who you're talking/writing to, after all.

Comment: What nuance does this have? To me, using the quote grammar sound like you actually listened to the girls conversation where she was telling someone else that she likes flowers. When I saw the English sentence I thought of something more like 花が好きだそうです. Do these have the same feeling?

Comment: This sentence means the girl said she likes flowers to a third person somewhere, and the speaker indirectly obtained that information from the third person. 花が好きだそうですね means the same thing (this ね is somehow mandatory).

Answer (score 1):

> (あなたは)花が好きだと聞きました。

Would be better when writing.
「好きだって 」is usually used in conversation.